# How do I get the last one click button player1 or player2

Tags: android, kotlin

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    enum class PLAYINGPLAYER {
        FIRST_PLAYER,
        SECOND_PLAYER
    }

    var playingplayer: PLAYINGPLAYER? = null
    var buttonClicked:ArrayList<Int> = ArrayList()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        playingplayer = PLAYINGPLAYER.FIRST_PLAYER
    }

    fun imgButtonClicked(v: View) {
        val btnselected = v as Button
        var optionNumber = 0

        when (btnselected.id) {
            R.id.btn1 -> optionNumber = 1
            R.id.btn2 -> optionNumber = 2
            R.id.btn3 -> optionNumber = 3
            R.id.btn4 -> optionNumber = 4
            R.id.btn5 -> optionNumber = 5
            R.id.btn6 -> optionNumber = 6
        }

        action(optionNumber, btnselected)
    }

    var button1Click = ArrayList<Button>()
    var button2Click = ArrayList<Button>()

    fun action(optionNumber: Int, btnselected: Button) {
        if (playingplayer == PLAYINGPLAYER.FIRST_PLAYER) {
            btnselected.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN)
            buttonClicked.add(optionNumber)
            btnselected.isEnabled = false
            button1Click.add(btnselected)
            playingplayer = PLAYINGPLAYER.SECOND_PLAYER
        }
        else if (playingplayer == PLAYINGPLAYER.SECOND_PLAYER) {
            btnselected.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)
            buttonClicked.add(optionNumber)
            btnselected.isEnabled = false
            button2Click.add(btnselected)
            playingplayer = PLAYINGPLAYER.FIRST_PLAYER
        }
        imagebtnState()
    }

    fun imagebtnState() {
        val btnLast = buttonClicked.get(buttonClicked.size - 1)

        if (buttonClicked.contains(1) && buttonClicked.contains(2)) {
            if ( btnLast == ??? player1 ) {
                imgbBtnBackground.setImageResource(R.drawable.rca)
            }
        }
        else if (buttonClicked.contains(1) && buttonClicked.contains(2)) {
            if ( btnLast == ??? player2 ) {
                imgbBtnBackground.setImageResource(R.drawable.wac)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have two players and several buttons. Player1 clicks on a button and player2 clicks on another button. When the players press several specific ?, I want to change the background of imageButton.

In (btnLast = ???) what I have put to get last one click in (buttonClicked.contains(1) && buttonClicked.contains(2)) is player1 or player2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are only ever going to have two players create a boolean called `var playerOneLastClicked = true` and if player one clicks set true, else if player two clicks set false

```
if (buttonClicked.contains(1) && buttonClicked.contains(2)) {
    if (playerOneLastClicked) {
        imgbBtnBackground.setImageResource(R.drawable.rca)
    } else {
        imgbBtnBackground.setImageResource(R.drawable.wac)
    }
}
```

Since `imagebtnState()` is called after each click it doesn't really matter about checking who clicked the last in the arrayList as the method does the check to see whether or not the specified buttons have been clicked anyway

I think that's that what you were asking for?

Comment: in (buttonClicked.contains(1) && buttonClicked.contains(2)) i want know who's last button click is 1 or 2 and who click this last button is player 1 or player 2 i hope you understand what i want say because i resarch for answer in two week

Comment: Yeah i can see that but as I said `imagebtnState()` is called after each button click is it not? Which means right after both criteria are met (buttonClicked.contains(1) && buttonClicked.contains(2)), the boolean I suggested would trigger; which indicates either player 1 clicking last or not

Comment: thanks it's working but when i click other button like 3 4 5 6 imgBtnBackground still change , i want when buttonClicked containt(1 and 2) imgBtnBackground don't change any more